# Jquery Get value from the input field and display them in 3 other input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code, when the ok button is clicked, it'll get the value in the done input field, and display in the text1,text2,text3 input field.
The problem is that all 3 column get the same value now (i.e. hi100).The desired result is all 3 column display different result which is hi100, hello100, sup100,
I'm wondering what went wrong with my code.Thanks

```js
if (typeof set == "undefined") {
  var set = $(".text").val();
}
$(".ok").on('click', function() {

  $(this).closest('tr').find(".text").val(set + $(this).closest('tr').find(".done").val());

});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
 
    <td>
      <input type="button"  value="ok" class="ok"></td>
    <td>done<input type="text" value="100" class="done" \> </td>
    <td>text1<textarea class="text">hi</textarea> </td>
    <td>text2<textarea class="text">hello</textarea> </td>
    <td>text3<textarea class="text">sup</textarea> </td>

  </tr>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your script to -

```
$(".ok").on('click', function() {
    var set = $(this).closest('tr').find('.done').val();
    if ( set ){
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.text').each(function(){
            $(this).val( $(this).val() + set );
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This
    $(this).closest('tr').find(".text").val(..) 
will use the value of the "first" found element with the "text" class. 
So it will always use the "hi" value.

What you need to do, is iterate all elements with the "text" class.
e.g.

```
//use $self as a reference to `$(this)`, since inside the function(currentInput)
//this will refer to the currently iterated "input"
var $self = $(this); 
$.each($(this).closest('tr').find(".text"), function(currentInput) {
    var valueToSet = $self.closest('tr').find(".done").val();
    currentInput.val(valueToSet);
});
```

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, This will allow you to set the value from the input field into each Textarea and it will remember the default value of each `.text`

```js
var obj = $('.text').map(function() {
  return $(this).val()
})
$(".ok").on('click', function() {
  var val = $(".done").val();
  $('.text').map(function(i,x) {
    $(this).val(obj[i] + val);
  })
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>

    <td>
      <input type="button" value="ok" class="ok"></td>
    <td>done<input type="text" value="100" class="done" \> </td>
    <td>text1<textarea class="text">hi</textarea> </td>
    <td>text2<textarea class="text">hello</textarea> </td>
    <td>text3<textarea class="text">sup</textarea> </td>

  </tr>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The below lines of code will set the value of `set` to value of first element returned by `$('.text')` i.e `hi` in this case.

```
if (typeof set == "undefined") {
  var set = $(".text").val(); 
}
```

So, use the following code in your javascript:

1. This code uses the function as an argument for `.val()`.
2. It uses the `.data()` methods of jQuery to store the initial values of the `.text` elements.
3. So, when you click `'.ok'` button, the function argument of `.val` method checks if initial value is set as `.data` attributes. If not it takes the current value as the initial value and appends it with the value in the `'.done'` input box. If the `.data` attribute is already set, it uses the value stored in `.data` instead of current value.

```js
$(".ok").on('click', function() {
  var doneValue = $(this).closest('tr').find('.done').val();
  
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.text').val(function(index, value){
     if($(this).data('value') === undefined){
        $(this).data('value', value);
     } else {
       value = $(this).data('value');
     }
     return value +  doneValue;
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
 
    <td>
      <input type="button"  value="ok" class="ok"></td>
    <td>done<input type="text" value="100" class="done" \> </td>
    <td>text1<textarea class="text">hi</textarea> </td>
    <td>text2<textarea class="text">hello</textarea> </td>
    <td>text3<textarea class="text">sup</textarea> </td>

  </tr>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```